# ASP.NET Membership / Identity MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am aware that MVC 5 uses Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, however I am still very confused working around it and I cant seem to figure how to do the equivalent of:

```
Membership.GetUser(username).IsOnline
```

The general purpose would be to get a list of online users.

Comment: Online users was never very accurate, and requires a lot of support from you as the developer.  I would suggest developing your own method of tracking this, so you understand exactly what it's doing and know that it's meeting your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in equivalent for IsOnline currently, you could replicate that functionality by tracking the last seen time for your users and then adding a method which checked whether they have been seen in the last 5 minutes.

We might add the last seen data to the default implementation in a future release.

Comment: Oh well thank you for the information anyway it helps clarify things.